# Nesta CMS on linux not show latest articles

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nestacms

Anyone experience an inability for **Nesta CMS** to show the latest articles on linux?  Running Ubuntu 12.04.

I can navigate to the article localhost:9393/filename and it shows up fine.  I have tried running under both shotgun and rackup with no difference.

But despite having a defined `Date: 03 Sept 2013` it still won't show.  On the actual page, the *published* is correctly showing the date, as well as the category.  But neither on the home page/category page, will the article's title/summary show up.

The odd thing is, pulling the same project down on a windows machine, adding a new article will allow it to show up properly on the home page for latest articles as well as the associated category page.

I have tinkered with different dates with no effect.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this turned out to be an issue with a Linux update.  After reboot everything worked as expected oddly enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching the articles with `latest_articles` helper method then try calling it with some number that is larger than 8, for example 30 `latest_articles(30)`, because by default it returns only 8 documents.